# Find out if inner div has overflown outer div

Tags: jquery, height, overflow

I'm looking for a way to find out if an inner div has overflown an outer div.

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
       <img src="#" alt="" />
       <img src="#" alt="" />
       <img src="#" alt="" />
       <img src="#" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

With JQuery i've already set #outer to a height of 400px and overflow:hidden. The inner div is automatically being filled with ajax images. So right now, i only see a part of #inner. How do i get JQuery to discover if #inner has more height than #outer?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you want the result to be? there is probably a css solution, and likewise for your other attributes

Answer (score 1):

You need to check whether `$('#inner').outerHeight()` is more than `$('#outer').height()`.

Comment: Yes, and i did that:

`var outer = $("#outer").outerHeight();
var inner = $("#inner").height();
`
Yet $inner gives 0..

Comment: you mean `inner` not `$inner`

Comment: @Math: That's probably because the images didn't load yet.

Comment: he would also have to take padding into consideration, right?  perhaps outerHeight would be appropriate here

Answer (score 1):

Compare the values of the `offsetHeight` properties of the outer and inner DIV's.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/gJbMf/

Answer (score 0):

Update (@Hussein)

```
(function($) {
$.fn.flickr = function(o){
   //FLICKR STUFF
};

if(o) $.extend(s, o);
return this.each(function(){

var list = $('<ul>').appendTo(this);
var url = $.flickr.format(s);
$.getJSON(url, function(r){
  // MORE FLICKR STUFF
};
 if (s.callback) s.callback(list);
    //START CALLBACK FUNCTION
        $('#photographs ul li a img').fadeTo('fast', 0.7);

        $('#photographs ul li a img').hover(function() {
            $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
            },function() {
            $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.7);
        });

        $("#photographs ul li a").fancybox({
            'hideOnContentClick': false,
            'zoomSpeedIn':      0, 
            'zoomSpeedOut': 0, 
            'overlayShow':      true,
            'overlayColor': '#000',
            'overlayOpacity': 0.9,
            'padding': 0
        });


            // OVERFLOW QUESTION SCRIPT - DOESN'T FIND INNER HEIGHT

           var outer = $('#photographs').outerHeight(),
           inner = $('#test').height();


           if(inner>outer){
               alert('Inner exceeded outer');
           }

      };
});
});
};
```

Comment: @manthijs, Analyzing your getJSON call should be another questions and we i need more details on that.  I already answered your question for this post and provided you with a live example to see Consider accepting the answer and open another question that relates to your code above.

Comment: Also you posted this as an answer. You shouldn't do that. it should be a comment and not an answer. You can get negative votes for this.

Comment: Ok, i'm sorry, i'm not used to this. Thank you for your help; i'll ask a new question!